# How to generate entity from existing table in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I have table "my_table" with some fields.
I want generate Entity in MyBundle used "my_table". But I don't want recreate all entities in MyBundle.
How can I do this?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

Answer (score 16):

Here is the way you can do it,

**First step**, ask Doctrine to introspect the database and generate the corresponding xml or yml metadata files.

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert [xml|yml] Path/To/MyBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force --filter=MyTable
```

**Second step**, ask Doctrine to import the schema and build related entity classes by executing the following two commands.

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import MyBundle [xml|yml|annotation] --filter=MyTable

php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Path\To\MyBundle\EntityFolder\\MyTable
```

Take a look at the [How to generate Entities from an Existing Database](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) section of the documentation

Comment: In the final command, I was able to use the shortcut `MyBundle:MyTable` in lieu of `Path\To\MyBundle\EntityFolder\\MyTable`

Answer (score 6):

Simple Working Solution for Symfony 2.7 option annotation and for [/xml/yml] see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

do 3 commands in 3 steps:

**Command #1:**

```
$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml --filter="Meeting"
```

Output:

> writing C:\xampp\htdocs\localxyz\src\AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Meeting.orm.xml

**Command #2:**

```
$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src/AppBundle/Entity --from-database --filter="Meeting"
```

Output:

> Processing entity "Meeting"
>
> Exporting "annotation" mapping information to "C:\xampp\htdocs\localxyz\src\Entity"

**Command #3:**

```
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Meeting --no-backup
```

Output:

> Generating entity "AppBundle\Entity\Meeting"
>   generating AppBundle\Entity\Meeting

where:

AppBundle is exactly your "AppBundle" in 2.7 symfony
Meeting is the target table (case sensitive)

TO BE SURE, check this directory:

C:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\src\AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Meeting.orm.xml

C:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\src\AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/MeetingOriginal.orm.xml

AND MAKING SURE you only have .xml files for the table you want to create entity class files and no others.

It works very well for me.

For explanation please read: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

Comment: This will work for a default entity manager.If you have to pull out the data from a different database then provide the below param
    --em="ENTITY MANGER NAME"

Answer (score 2):

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import "MyCustomBundle" xml --filter=MyMatchedEntity
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old post but if someone gets following error,

`Database does not have any mapping information.`

Check

**If your table name is `blog_post` then in filter option use `BlogPost` and not `blog_post`**

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27019561/6504104

though this is covered by answers above but I missed it and was getting this error

So I wanted to make this explicit

Also in symfony >= 3.4 its' `php bin/console` e.g.

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml --filter="BlogPost"
```

and then

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src/AppBundle/Entity --from-database --filter="BlogPost"
```

Thanks...