# how to import entities schemas(oracle 11g ) in symfony 3

Tags: oracle, symfony

I have an existing Oracle database from a previous project and this DB contains a lot of `schema`...

**in configuration Doctrine**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   oci8
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"




        charset:  UTF8
        mapping_types:
                     enum: string
                     set: string
                     varbinary: string
                     tinyblob: text
                     point: string


    orm:
       auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
       auto_mapping: true
```

**in Parameters**

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 1521
    database_name: database
    database_user: root
    database_password: ******
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: 4b9862cf9f801cdd6b25eefc7e2c7d88808a655d
```

My tables exists in Schema Global in Oracle. The problem is when I use `cmd php bin/console`'s `doctrine:mapping:import --force` `MainDashboardBundle` annotation to import entities from database but i get this error:

> Database does not have any mapping information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating entities from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347164/generating-entities-from-database)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't solved this yet, for building the entities from an existing database you just need to create some metadata files first by using this command

> php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml

and after that you can create the entity classes with your command:

> php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src

Tell us if this worked for you