# Doctrine/Symfony entity generator and generating entity from one table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I have already a few entities, but now a new table appeared in a database, and I'd like to generate an entity on only this one table.

I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394855/how-to-generate-entity-from-existing-table-in-symfony2), but I have further questions.

I already have a User entity (and a db table). Now, the new table is called "Report" (no entity for it right now, I want to create it) and it has a foreign key to User. There are also a few more foreign keys.

If I do what is suggested in the above answer, that is:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml --filter="Report"

$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src/AppBundle/Entity --from-database --filter="Report"

$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Report --no-backup
```

Will Doctrine generator try to modify my User entity? Or will just create a Report entity?

Btw. I understand(?), this it will not, because this is ManyToOne relation, but let's assume for a moment that this is ManyToMany for a moment.

I know I could simply try it, but the last time I executed the `doctrine:mapping:import --force` command I ended up with a crashing app and I spent many hours to solve this problem, until someone on Stackoverflow told me to remove the `src\AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/` directory, which helped.

I didn't think about making a backup before running this command.

So, I'm a bit afraid of it... Now I created a backup, but I'm not sure if this will help in case of troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the `/Resources/config/doctrine` directory.  If you empty it out and do the commands you described, then only the `Report` entity will be modified.  If you have all of the previous mappings in that directory it should modify the `User` entity as well.

The commands will automatically create backups of your entities for you, so you will have a new `User.php` and a backup in `User.php~`, which you should be careful of if you are using version control and like to `git add src/` without thinking too hard about it.  You don't want to add those files to source control.

Either way, backups are created, and you should be using version control on top of that, so you should be fine.

Comment: OK, thank you for this second answer to my questions from you today :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help. If the other one worked don't forget to set as the accepted answer :)

Comment: Ahh indeed, forgive me, Stackoverflow said I have to wait 10 minutes (or something like that) and then I forgot about it. Now it's done, thanks again!