# In Symfony, what's the purpose of src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/*.orm.yml files?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I wanted to create an entity, basing on a database table. I followed these steps: [Doctrine/Symfony entity generator and generating entity from one table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35225929/doctrine-symfony-entity-generator-and-generating-entity-from-one-table) , that is, in terminal:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle yml --force --filter="Client"

php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src/AppBundle/Entity --from-database --filter="Client"

php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Client --no-backup
```

This created the entity "Client". But, it also created a client.orm.yml file in the src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine directory. And this causes problems - that is, my application now crashes with an error message:

> "No mapping file found named 'User.orm.yml' for class
>   'AppBundle\Entity\User'"

I think Symfony/Doctrine started using those yml files to map my php code to database schema. But why? I didn't want it. I just wanted Doctrine to create an entity.

p.s. When I remove this client.orm.yml file, everything works fine. But I don't understand what is happening, and how should I handle it properly.

Comment: You can delete these files after entity creation process. These files for metadata mapping. You can read this http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/metadataMapping.html and http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html

Comment: @MertÖksüz Although I still don't understand why Doctrine doesn't do this (delete those files), and instead gives me a rather strange error message, but... thank you for the links! I've never thought there are so many patterns I didn't know :)

Comment: Why doctrine does not delete ? Because, it is first step for convert process. Your first command creating those files after you command to doctrine and it is creating Entity files referenced with those files. :)

Comment: @MertÖksüz OK thanks. If you add this as an answer then obviously I'll accept it. And thanks again for the links!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete these files after entity creation process. These files for metadata mapping.

You can read this 
[martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/metadataMapping.html](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/metadataMapping.html) and [martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)

Why doctrine does not delete ? Because, it is first step for convert process. Your first command creating those files after you command to doctrine and it is creating Entity files referenced with those files. :)

Comment: Within: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html 

It mentions: "If you want to use annotations, you must remove the XML (or YAML) files after running this command. This is necessary as it is not possible to mix mapping configuration formats" 
  
Chances are you want to delete the Yaml files once the Entities have been created to avoid issues in future.